# Is it possible to create a VM that with Puppet?

Tags: virtual-machine, puppet

I wonder if we could create a VM server with Puppet? I have searched Puppet Labs home site and found out that it seems possible to create a server in AWS could with Puppet Enterprise version, but what about open source version of puppet? Dose anyone know the answer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to manage your cloud resources using Puppet. Modules like puppetlabs-aws (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-aws) may help.
However, I'd prefer to use the cloud environment's internal services (e.g. AWS CloudFormation) to manage resources and use puppet just to provision instances (i.e. configure them after being spin up by CloudFormation)